# Why my simple SVG is invalid?

Tags: xml, svg

I've tried to create a SVG file with a line. I don't want to define the style properties directly inside the style="..." attribute. Note that I add "&E1" inside the style attribute because I want to use the entity. Here's my attempt

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"[
    <!ENTITY E1 'stroke-miterlimit:9;stroke-linecap:butt;opacity:1;stroke-width:1;fill:none;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke:rgb(255,0,0);'>
]>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="q_svg" version="1.1">
      <g id="root_group" style="shape-rendering:crispEdges;">
    <line x1="0" x2="12" y2="56" id="2" style="&E1;" y1="0" />
  </g>
</svg>

</body></html>
```

What went wrong?

Comment: I don't think you can nest `<!DOCTYPE` declarations like that - they define the type of the whole document, not some fragment of it.

Comment: So how do I fix it? I'm learning, otherwise I wouldn't have asked here. I'm confused.

Comment: I don't know the details, that's why I posted a comment not an answer; hopefully someone will come along and give a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: Have you looked for existing questions on using custom entities in html? I'd recommend using a style element with the contents of the E1 entity instead (rewritten as a css stylerule).

Answer (score 2):

One thing is the way you state DOCTYPE for svg. I don't think it is necessary to declare it for SVG and dtd declaration should be at top of the document. Another is that I believe it is important to let the browser be aware that the document is of XML/XHTML, not HTML/HTML5, because custom DTD entities can only be part of an XML. If it is a file, better name its extension as .xml; if it is generated on the fly, set content type to  "application/xhtml+xml" or perhaps "application/xml".
Below snippet may work for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html 
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"
[
  <!ENTITY E1 'stroke-miterlimit:9;stroke-linecap:butt;opacity:1;stroke-width:1;fill:none;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke:rgb(255,0,255);'>
]>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml;charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Entities in XHTML</title>
</head>
<body>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="q_svg" version="1.1">
    <g id="root_group" style="shape-rendering:crispEdges;">
      <line x1="0" x2="12" y2="56" id="2" style="&E1;" y1="0" />
    </g>
  </svg>

</body>
</html>
```

FYI. [HTML parser does not support embedded entity declaration](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-comments/2011Sep/0001.html).